# QLibrary how to get the absolutive Path of the Library

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I am new to QT Development.

I have loaded the library dynamically like this:

```
1) QLibrary  lobj ("myLib");
```

And, to resolve the functions inside the library,

```
2) lobj.resolve ("Fun1");  -> Store the function pointer. i have not writting here. ;).
```

and i could able to invoke the function Fun1, successfully.

**Question:**

I would like to get the absolute path of the library  "myLib" which is loaded.

I tried using **filename()** method, but it returns only the library name, unless we explictly 
specify the absolute path while loading the library.

Kindly provide suggession?.

Answer (score 0):

There's no portable way for that. Check the source, on Unix there is a [loop](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/plugin/qlibrary_unix.cpp#line226) which tries several prefixes and suffixes, but no logic for remembering the chosen file name. I suspect the situation is probably similar on other platforms as well.

It might be interesting to know why you need to know the library name in the first place. You can also duplicate the logic of the prefix & suffix resolution yourself and remember the chose file name, but that's going to be a lot of (unportable) effort.

Comment: I have the same library installed into different locations across the system, and would like to remove unused entries. that's why i required. :).

Comment: If you're on Linux, check the output of `ldd` to see which library gets picked. If it's something you load at runtime, `strace` the program. I'm sure there are similar tools for other platforms.